# GraphQL: How to resolve coprrectly a query which has a return type of boolean

Tags: javascript, postgresql, graphql, knex.js

In my application with GraphQL and PostgreSQL with KnexJS query builder,
I'm trying to build a query which has to check if in a DB we have an exact match for a recipient based on a email, phone or both.

My issue I'm new to GraphQL and I'm not sure what should be the approach to return the Boolean of the query.

I should return true or false based on below cases.

Scenario cases:

1. When phone and no email → count recipients with exact match phone number → return true if count > 0, otherwise false
2. When no phone and yes email → count recipients with exact match email → return true if count > 0, otherwise false
3. When phone and email → count recipients with exact match phone and exact match email → return true if count > 0, otherwise false

The GraphQL query:

`recipientByContact(phone: String, email: String): Boolean!`

The resolver I have just this query:

```
Query: {
    recipientByContact(_, args, user) {
      return recipientService(user).getRecipientByContact(args);
    },
```

The service which communicate with DB:

```
getRecipientByContact({ email, phone }) {
    const { UserInputError } = this.errors;

    if (isEmpty(email) && isEmpty(phone))
      throw new UserInputError(`Specify an email or phone number`);

    return (async ({ recipient }) => {
      const existContact = await recipient.selectByContact({ email, phone });
      console.log('existContact', existContact);
    });
```

DB side:

```
selectByContact(email, phone) {

    if (email) this.tx(tableName).where(columns.email, email);
    if (phone) this.tx(tableName).where(columns.phone, phone);

    return this;
  }
```

At the moment the error I'm getting

```
Cannot return null for non-nullable field Query.recipientByContact.
```

The expected output of this are the 3 cases above to give an e.g.

1. recipientByContact(phone: "+4512345698", email: "email@email.com")
   Phone and email passes check exact match > 0 return true otherwise false
2. recipientByContact(phone: "+4512345698") Phone exact check > 0 return true otherwise false
3. recipientByContact(email: "email@email.com") Email exact check > 0 return true otherwise false

If any of above seems not clear or missing just leave a comment and I will provide an edit or an explanation.

Comment: `recipientByContact` is the boolean field?

Comment: `getRecipientByContact` returns a function which is pretty weird. Are you calling that anywhere? Do you ever get the log `existContact`? If not, it's not a graphql problem.

Comment: `recipientByContact`is the name of the query which checks if we have a match with phone, email or both of a recipient and the result is `Boolean!`

Comment: OK - if you're still open to change the schema, I'd recommend to rename that to `hasRecipientByContact` or `recipientWithContactExists` or something more descriptive and more boolean :-) (`recipientByContact` would be the name of a field that returns the found recipient)

Comment: I cannot change naming was decided by my manager and what I done until now is this https://pastebin.com/zuWH7vCk and I have the console working and seeing when is false/true but not sure is the right approach

Comment: I don't know what `this.withDAO` does but if it works then it works. You might want to ask your manager whether this is the right approach, they should be more familiar with your codebase than me.